# Why does maximum likelihood estimation not work in estimating signal in deterministic chaotic noise

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have few conceptual questions related to application of chaos in communications. In few application such as radar [Chaotic signal reconstruction with application to noise radar system](http://asp.eurasipjournals.com/content/pdf/1687-6180-2011-2.pdf), cryptography, the noise considered is chaotic in nature. Why does MLE not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is provided in the abstract of the paper you cited (and the title of your question):

> Since a chaotic signal is inherently deterministic ...

So, MLE is not applicable in this case given that they are assuming that the signal/noise is deterministic, and therefore not random (an essential assumption in the context of maximum likelihood estimation). Whether or not this is a sensible assumption is open to debate.